# Is "could not have been done" more appropriate here?

Tags: spoken-english, could-modal

An extract from today's newspaper:

> Despite our best efforts and the hard work of various organizations, the boy **could not be retrieved so far.**

Should I use: ...the boy **could not have been retrieved so far** instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that would only be used in a narrative provided after the situation was over.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first option works in this case although, if the boy is alive, he would be **rescued** rather than retrieved. If he had died, his body might be **retrieved**. (So I shall use **rescued** rather than **retrieved**.)

The construction **could not be rescued so far** is another way of saying that **so far the rescuers have not been able to rescue him.**

The second construction **could not have been rescued** would apply - without **so far** - in different circumstances, for example, if the boy had been rescued:

> The boy **could not have been rescued** without the hard work of several organisations.

It is saying that the hard work of several organisations was essential to the rescue.

I disagree with the suggested construction **was not retrieved so far**, by books4languages.com

If rescue efforts were continuing, one would say: the boy **has not been** rescued so far - using the imperfect rather than the past tense.